# foreach for two column in select option using mvc php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, opencart

I'm very new in MVC pattern using opencart 2.3.0.2. I try to create new field for username selection for add new product. The field what i want to do is drop down list using foreach. This is what i customize.

Database user table
[image: user table]

model/catalog/product/product.php file

```
<..some php code..>
public function getUser()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT username, user_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user");
    return $query->row;
}
<..some php code..>
```

controller/catalog/controller/product.php file

```
<..some php code..>
public function add()
{   
   <..some php code..>
   $this->load->model('catalog/product');
   <..some php code..>
   $this->getFormAdd();
}
protected function getFormAdd() 
{
  $theLists = $this->model_catalog_product->getUser();
  $data['theLists'][] = array(
        'username' => $theLists['username'],
        'user_id' => $theLists['user_id']
   );
<..some php code..>
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('catalog/product_formadd', $data));
}
```

view/catalog/product/product_formadd.tpl

```
<..some html code..>
<select style="background-color: FloralWhite;" name="filter_username" id="input-username" class="form-control">
        <option value="*">Select Name</option>
        <?php foreach ($username as $usernames) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $user_ids; ?>" selected><?php echo $usernames; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>  
</select>
<..some html code..>
```

The website didnt show up the changes i done. Did i miss something out? Please help me! Fill free to ask me if miss understand. I will explain more. Thank in advance.

Comment: What if you do ->rows instead of ->row? I am not familiar with opencart but I would think that ->row returns exactly one row. 

Also, where do you put theLists into userNames ?

What is the expected result and what do you see?

Comment: @JakubJudas i already tried put rows instead of row, but same result.. i want to shows result of drop down list..show the username with value as user id..any other suggestion?

Comment: Where do you fill the $username variable? Can you iterate over $theLists instead? (I am not famailiar with opencart, but it seems that that is where it would put a variable that you set as $data['theLists'] in the controller.)

Comment: The $username and $user id is calling from controller file which contain the array of username and user id. Actually i want to display the both variables using foreach method..Is it correct?